# Can not get customer birthday, total orders and total order amount from admin api

Tags: axios, shopware6

I'm trying to fetch some customer information using admin API, everything goes fine except for the birthday which is always null and the orderTotalAmount and orderCount always being 0, is there something wrong in my query?

I tried this api call:

```
const newTotals = await AxiosShopware.get(
      `/api/customer/${order.orderCustomer.customerId}`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        data: {
          includes: {
            customer: []
          }
        }
      }
    );
```

with or without the includes: `{customer: []}` and with includes: `{customer: ["birthday", "orderTotalAmount", "orderCount" ]`

what was I expecting:

```
data: {
       ....
       birthday: "1983-12-17"
       orderTotalAmount: 100
       orderCount: 10          
}
```

what I got:

```
data: {
     birthday: null,
     orderTotalAmount: 0,
     orderCount: 0,
}
```